# Where can I find area specific SST data

Tags: data-request, climate, oceanographic

I am looking for sea surface temperature (SST) data for the Cayman Islands from 1972-2017. Can anyone point me toward a resource? I have checked out NOAA and NASA, but I cannot seem to access the data in a CSV or Excel format.

EDIT:
I found this website, but it only has air temp, not SST. 
http://sdwebx.worldbank.org/climateportal/index.cfm?page=downscaled_data_download&menu=historical

Comment: can you add the links to the resources you found? perhaps with some coding someone can transform the data to CSV

Comment: Is [this NOAA datasource](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oisst) one of the ones you found? Looks like there's companion software that may allow conversion & filtering if that's the right data.

Comment: Do you know what software this is? Please and thank you.

Comment: There are a few options in the `Viewing Tools and Codes` section of the [data access page](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oisst/data-access). I'm not familiar with any of those tools so I can't give specific recommendations at this time.